# Receive email notifications

Tags: support, notifications, email-notification

If someone posts an answer to a question days after it was posted, how can I receive an email message to inform me that there is a response to one of my posts?

And can I control the e-mail address to which I want this information be send?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That answer doesn't have freehand circles! It must be burned.

Comment: @J.Steen: You can [add them yourself](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-s) (with or without blowtorch-freehand-drawn scorch marks)!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh. My. GOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You click the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/199700) at the top left, click the *very tiny* "email settings" in the popover that appears, and then it should be self-explanatory.